# opening a fixed window on 'onclick' event - javascript & html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that there is some manner to show a new window, fixed on screen, while another part of site gonna disable and on under of a dark and transparent cover. But **I do not know these ways and techniques names**. So I write my own codes to create something like them. **My question** is, what is the common method for doing this? here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg_cover">
</div>
<div id="inside_box">
</div>
<div>
    <form>
        <label>
            <input type="button" value="run" onclick="sign_go()">
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function sign_go() {
        document.getElementById('bg_cover').style='z-index:80; background-color:#003399; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%; opacity:0.5;';
        document.getElementById('inside_box').style='z-index:90; background-color:white; position:fixed; left:0; right:0; height:100px; width:300px; margin:auto; margin-top:100px;';
        document.getElementById('inside_box').innerHTML='<form><label><input type="text"><input type="button" onclick="sign_back()"></label></form>';
     }
    function sign_back(){
        document.getElementById('bg_cover').style='';
        document.getElementById('inside_box').style='';
        document.getElementById('inside_box').innerHTML='';
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: try searching for jquery modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need a fixed element to cover the whole page and be transparent with a higher z-index and `display: none;`, the content will go inside. So it'll look like:

```
<div id="center_container">
    <div id="center">
        <div>Some content</div>
        <span id="close_center">X</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

`#center` will hold the contents here and `#center_container` just cover the page.

```
#center_container {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5); /* transparency */
    z-index: 20;
}
#center {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#close_center {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And then on a button click you show it and set close button to close it.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/ex5ztygf/)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is called modal. You can create it using jQuery or pure CSS. Check out below article to create model.

Check out this article to create [jQuery Modal](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/)

Or Pure [CSS3 Modal](http://goo.gl/MFQVPk)